# Use HDMI for audio ouput only

Tags: xorg, hdmi

I am looking for a solution that lets me use my HDMI port for audio output without extending my X screen to that output at the same time.

Apparently it is problematic to use HDMI for audio only, because it seems inseparable from video output. I can hear my music as long as the video output is on. This implies extending my screen to a second output, which is only counterproductive and I really don't want that.

When I turn it off `xrandr --output HDMI1 --off`, the output is also unavailable for audio output. I found [one related forum thread](http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/57484-6-running-hdmi-audio-receiver) which basically confirms that audio only is not an intended use case. So I need to create this effect.

I can think of one or two cumbersome approaches, but I really hope someone has already satisfactory solved this problem. How can I use an HDMI output for audio without having to extend my screen to that output as well?

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfactory solution? I'm having the exact same problem with GNOME on Arch Linux, and the only solution I can think of would be to fix the display configuration so that the joined displays can overlap. Then the virtual display wouldn't extend beyond the actual monitor. Basically what should be doable with something like `xrandr --output XWAYLAND1 --pos 0x0`.

Comment: No, I did not. You can mirror outputs using `xrandr --output XYZ1 --same-as XYZ0` and as long as these outputs support the same resolutions, this won't cause any problems. And then I settled for displays that are on a lot more than they need to.

Comment: The latest proprietary Nvidia driver is the first time I've seen this handled in a reasonable manner: `nvidia-settings` doesn't show the receiver (connected via HDMI, used for audio only) *at all,* but it is still usable by PulseAudio. Hopefully this isn't just another bug where eventually the receiver will be disabled by the Nvidia drivers or something.